event cli_task_run is 2 times more than count of event "running"
In this doc https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/audit_logs.html I found

cli_task_run: Airflow triggered a task instance

I export metrics into Grafana throw this exporter and see that count of event "cli_task_run" is two times more than count of event "running".
Why is this happening?
I expected that count of event "cli_task_run" is the same as count of event "running"
